# What was the meaning of Leo's chant on episode 10?

Tags: kekkai-sensen

In episode 10, around 15:10 mark, just when Leo is about to collapse from hunger before they finally agree to settle for the burger place where he usually goes, he chants something that appears in the subtitles as:

> Onbutsu sowaka mareba eloim essaza...

What's that supposed to mean?
Is it a reference to something I'm not getting?

Comment: On first inspection, it kind of looks like a reference to Buddhist chants. "Eloim" also resembles the Hebrew word "Elohim" which is used in Jewish religious chants. This is just wild speculation, though; I haven't seen the show, so I don't know if that would even make sense in context.

Comment: ^To add a context, Leo seems to meet "God of Chow" (probably "God of Food" or something) before inside his mind and he thinks that the god is angry, so he offers a pray... now back to the question, to be honest, I couldn't hear Leo's chant clear enough with others' conversation and background song, so I doubt the fansub means anything except general chants by some religions. (What I heard: "Ra~zaza.... Ra~~ra~~ararara [*scene change*] [...] wareware [...] wareware [...]")